# Android Softkeyboard predictive text

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to get the list of all predictive words based on user input I am using android Softkeyboard sample any idea how should I move on

Regards
Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

Store all the words in a SQLite databse.Thenfor each keypress look for word in database starting with composing text through cursor using like statement and store them in a list. Show this list to the candidate view and you are done :)